# Datecs bluepad-50 and android phone pairing

Tags: android, bluetooth

I have [this device](http://www.datecs.bg/en/products/BluePad-50/9/331#) and I have been playing around with [this SDK](http://www.datecs.bg/en/products/Java-Printer-SDK/8/109) for android which makes the communication with the device possible.

I have compiled the application and installed on my phone. When opening the application on the phone it will search for the device and connect to it via bluetooth.

My problem now is that the bluetooth setting on the device is disabled and I have been looking for how to enable it, even searched online for the documentation but no information on that so far.

I will appreciate if anybody has any helpful information on this. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

According to tech support, you don't enable or disable Bluetooth on the '50...it comes on when the '50 is powered-up.  All the work to do the connection/pairing is done via the Android Bluetooth setup menu:

"There’s a power button that you hold for 3 seconds to turn on and off. Once it’s on you can pair to it using your device BT Pairing menu. In the menu the device’s serial number will be displayed. It uses Secure Simple Pairing so it will not require a passcode. Once you’re connected you can use the SDK demo application to run test swipes and pin entry."

Answer (score 0):

This device can lockout when the internal battery goes flat, recharging will not solve this.

Pressing "C" + "<-" will get you to a password screen to allow a reset.

I don't know the passwords though, you need to contact support.. http://www.datecs.bg/en/support

Comment: Here is a listed password and instructions to reset the device. https://handpoint.atlassian.net/wiki/display/PD/Resetting+the+Flash+Memory

Answer (score 0):

On the Bluepad-50, you press the "<-" button to get into the Menu, then go to Settings and then Bluetooth. Make sure "Mode" is "Enabled". To toggle, just press the the green "OK" or "tick" button on the bottom right of the keypad.